# How to make a constant current source of 5 amps running through the load of 30 ohms

Tags: constant-current

I have two batteries connected in series of each 12 volts and each rating at 35 AH.

I have tried with voltage multiplier boosting the voltage upto 150 volts so that the current could be climbed upto 5 amps but that didnt work .
Please give the solution for having the load current of 5 amps that runs through 30 ohms load and 24 volt input.

Comment: A boost regulator should work. The input current to the regulator will be something like 35 Amps. So use thick wire.

Comment: @mkeith, looks like OP edited to clarify. Deleting my comment.

Comment: To the OP, 35 Amps is just a very quick rough calculation. My main point is that boost regulators have higher input current than output current, due to conservation of energy, and also do to inefficiency (some energy is converted to heat).

Comment: "I have tried with voltage multiplier boosting the voltage upto 150 volts... but that didnt work" - that's what you need to do. What circuit did you use, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Instead of telling us 'it didn't work', tell us what it *did* do. Did it only manage 4.9A, did it manage 0.49A, did it flatten the batteries, did the input wire fuse.

Comment: Bruce abbott , Neil_UK21 -  the capacitance is not enough to hold the charge long enough for 30 ohms load...capacitance is 10000uf ..when no load is connected i get around 150 volts but if load is connected i get around only 15 volts. it is not able to maintain the voltage since its charging and discharging cycle is not competiting the 30 ohms load.i have also varied the frequency of charging and discharging cycles, but couldnt resolve...if anyone can help me with this voltage multiplier's frequency in charging and discharging please give a comment.